# Why is the number of orientations of order $n$ equal to $3^\binom{n}{2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

I read that in West's *Introduction to Graph Theory*, but no proof was provided. I get that there are $\binom{n}{2}$ edges in a graph, but I have no clue where the $3$ comes in.

Comment: There are $3$ possible orientations for an edge: forward arrow, reverse arrow, and bidirectional.

Comment: Also, for tournaments a similar argument holds for $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$ because there is no bidirectional? Also, you can put an answer and I'll give you the check. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on context, it could be that for each pair of vertices, there is either an edge, or else an edge in two possible directions. This would give the expression you quoted. A bidirectional arrow is not oriented.

Comment: Ahh, so Riley's answer is wrong. EDIT: He corrected it.

Comment: @Somos Yes, I understand now. I was thinking of a complete directed graph, instead of an oriented graph. I've fixed my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $3$ possible orientations for each edge of an oriented graph: forward arrow, reverse arrow, and no arrow. So $3^\binom{n}{2}$ is the total number of orientations. If you are only counting tournaments, then the orientation of "no arrow" is not valid, so the answer would be $2^\binom{n}{2}$